# Depth in SVNClient (JavaHL)

Tags: depth, javahl

I am trying to use the correct (non-deprecated) versions of Add/checkout/commit etc, but these actions want an int of "Depth".  In the program I am writing I don't always know the depth.  It would be nice to use the INFINITY 'keyword' similar to using SVN from command line with --depth.

However I don't see how to do this in the Java code using SVNClient from javahl.

Is my best bet just to slap Integer.MAX to 'simulate' infinity depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

int depthInfinity = org.tigris.subversion.javahl.Depth.infity;